# i can't deserializing into JSON in C#. Is it something wrong with my classes?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, dotnet-httpclient

I'm having trouble when trying to deserialize a string into JSON.

I'm making a call to a API. The answer I get is stored in a variable (`body`):

```
Root Api = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(body);
//var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(body);

public partial class All
{
    public int matchsPlayed { get; set; }
    public int win { get; set; }
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int lose { get; set; }
    public int goalsFor { get; set; }
    public int goalsAgainst { get; set; }
}

public partial class Home
{
    public int matchsPlayed { get; set; }
    public int win { get; set; }
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int lose { get; set; }
    public int goalsFor { get; set; }
    public int goalsAgainst { get; set; }
}

public partial class Away
{
    public int matchsPlayed { get; set; }
    public int win { get; set; }
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int lose { get; set; }
    public int goalsFor { get; set; }
    public int goalsAgainst { get; set; }
}

public partial class Standings // Offers
{
    public int rank { get; set; }
    public int team_id { get; set; }
    public string teamName { get; set; }
    public string logo { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
    public string forme { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public All all { get; set; }
    public Home home { get; set; }
    public Away away { get; set; }
    public int goalsDiff { get; set; }
    public int points { get; set; }
    public string lastUpdate { get; set; }
}



public partial class Api // ProductListing
{
    public int results { get; set; }
   // public Standings[] Standings { get; set; }
    public List<Standings> standings { get; set; }
}

public partial class Root // RootObject
{
    public Api api { get; set; }
}
```

I get this error message:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
> 'Standings' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g.
> {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either
> change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the
> deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection
> interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be
> deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added
> to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

"

This is the whole JSON text I'm trying to deserialize:

> {"api":{"results":1,"standings":[[{"rank":1,"team_id":45,"teamName":"Everton","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/45.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DWWWW","status":"same","description":"Promotion - Champions League (Group Stage)","all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":4,"draw":1,"lose":0,"goalsFor":14,"goalsAgainst":7},"home":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":2,"draw":1,"lose":0,"goalsFor":11,"goalsAgainst":6},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":0,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":1},"goalsDiff":7,"points":13,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":2,"team_id":66,"teamName":"Aston Villa","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/66.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"WWWW","status":"same","description":"Promotion - Champions League (Group Stage)","all":{"matchsPlayed":4,"win":4,"draw":0,"lose":0,"goalsFor":12,"goalsAgainst":2},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":0,"goalsFor":8,"goalsAgainst":2},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":0,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":0},"goalsDiff":10,"points":12,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":3,"team_id":40,"teamName":"Liverpool","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/40.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DLWWW","status":"same","description":"Promotion - Champions League (Group Stage)","all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":3,"draw":1,"lose":1,"goalsFor":13,"goalsAgainst":13},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":0,"goalsFor":7,"goalsAgainst":4},"away":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":1,"goalsFor":6,"goalsAgainst":9},"goalsDiff":0,"points":10,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":4,"team_id":46,"teamName":"Leicester","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/46.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"LLWWW","status":"same","description":"Promotion - Champions League (Group Stage)","all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":3,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":12,"goalsAgainst":8},"home":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":6},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":0,"goalsFor":8,"goalsAgainst":2},"goalsDiff":4,"points":9,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":5,"team_id":42,"teamName":"Arsenal","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/42.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"LWLWW","status":"same","description":"Promotion - Europa League (Group Stage)","all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":3,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":8,"goalsAgainst":6},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":0,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":2},"away":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":4},"goalsDiff":2,"points":9,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":6,"team_id":39,"teamName":"Wolves","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/39.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"WWLLW","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":3,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":5,"goalsAgainst":7},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":1,"draw":0,"lose":1,"goalsFor":2,"goalsAgainst":3},"away":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":1,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":4},"goalsDiff":-2,"points":9,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":7,"team_id":47,"teamName":"Tottenham","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/47.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DWDWL","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":2,"draw":2,"lose":1,"goalsFor":15,"goalsAgainst":8},"home":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":0,"draw":2,"lose":1,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":5},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":0,"goalsFor":11,"goalsAgainst":3},"goalsDiff":7,"points":8,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":8,"team_id":49,"teamName":"Chelsea","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/49.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DWDLW","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":2,"draw":2,"lose":1,"goalsFor":13,"goalsAgainst":9},"home":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":1,"goalsFor":7,"goalsAgainst":5},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":0,"goalsFor":6,"goalsAgainst":4},"goalsDiff":4,"points":8,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":9,"team_id":48,"teamName":"West Ham","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/48.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DWWLL","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":2,"draw":1,"lose":2,"goalsFor":11,"goalsAgainst":7},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":1,"draw":0,"lose":1,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":2},"away":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":1,"goalsFor":7,"goalsAgainst":5},"goalsDiff":4,"points":7,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":10,"team_id":63,"teamName":"Leeds","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/63.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"LDWWL","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":2,"draw":1,"lose":2,"goalsFor":9,"goalsAgainst":9},"home":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":1,"goalsFor":5,"goalsAgainst":5},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":1,"draw":0,"lose":1,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":4},"goalsDiff":0,"points":7,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":11,"team_id":50,"teamName":"Manchester City","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/50.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"WDLW","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":4,"win":2,"draw":1,"lose":1,"goalsFor":7,"goalsAgainst":7},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":1,"draw":0,"lose":1,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":5},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":0,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":2},"goalsDiff":0,"points":7,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":12,"team_id":41,"teamName":"Southampton","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/41.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DWWLL","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":2,"draw":1,"lose":2,"goalsFor":8,"goalsAgainst":9},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":1,"draw":0,"lose":1,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":5},"away":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":1,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":4},"goalsDiff":-1,"points":7,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":13,"team_id":34,"teamName":"Newcastle","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/34.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"LWDLW","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":2,"draw":1,"lose":2,"goalsFor":7,"goalsAgainst":9},"home":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":8},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":0,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":1},"goalsDiff":-2,"points":7,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":14,"team_id":52,"teamName":"Crystal Palace","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/52.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DLLWW","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":2,"draw":1,"lose":2,"goalsFor":6,"goalsAgainst":8},"home":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":1,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":3},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":1,"draw":0,"lose":1,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":5},"goalsDiff":-2,"points":7,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":15,"team_id":33,"teamName":"Manchester United","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/33.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"WLWL","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":4,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":9,"goalsAgainst":12},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":0,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":2,"goalsAgainst":9},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":0,"goalsFor":7,"goalsAgainst":3},"goalsDiff":-3,"points":6,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":16,"team_id":51,"teamName":"Brighton","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/51.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DLLWL","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":3,"goalsFor":9,"goalsAgainst":11},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":0,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":6},"away":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":1,"goalsFor":6,"goalsAgainst":5},"goalsDiff":-2,"points":4,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":17,"team_id":60,"teamName":"West Brom","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/60.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DLDLL","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":0,"draw":2,"lose":3,"goalsFor":5,"goalsAgainst":13},"home":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":0,"draw":2,"lose":1,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":6},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":0,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":2,"goalsAgainst":7},"goalsDiff":-8,"points":2,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":18,"team_id":44,"teamName":"Burnley","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/44.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DLLL","status":"same","description":"Relegation - Championship","all":{"matchsPlayed":4,"win":0,"draw":1,"lose":3,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":8},"home":{"matchsPlayed":1,"win":0,"draw":0,"lose":1,"goalsFor":0,"goalsAgainst":1},"away":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":0,"draw":1,"lose":2,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":7},"goalsDiff":-5,"points":1,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":19,"team_id":62,"teamName":"Sheffield Utd","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/62.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DLLLL","status":"same","description":"Relegation - Championship","all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":0,"draw":1,"lose":4,"goalsFor":2,"goalsAgainst":7},"home":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":0,"draw":1,"lose":2,"goalsFor":1,"goalsAgainst":4},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":0,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":1,"goalsAgainst":3},"goalsDiff":-5,"points":1,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"},{"rank":20,"team_id":36,"teamName":"Fulham","logo":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/36.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DLLLL","status":"same","description":"Relegation - Championship","all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":0,"draw":1,"lose":4,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":12},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":0,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":0,"goalsAgainst":6},"away":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":0,"draw":1,"lose":2,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":6},"goalsDiff":-8,"points":1,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-19"}]]}}

Comment: `standings` looks weird in your JSON - its an array of arrays.

Comment: Why is the standings array value enclosed in double brackets `[[...]]´?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the definition of `Api` so `standings` is a list of lists it should work as the JSON has an array of arrays.

```
public partial class Api // ProductListing
{
    public int results { get; set; }
    public List<List<Standings>> standings { get; set; }
}
```